# Most correct way to pass dataobjects among ViewModels in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a Xamarin.Form app, using Prism for MVVM, navigation, DI.
In a Page I download a dataobject from a WS, and I need to maintain it along with other dataobjects downloaded along the way (along with states, flags that doesn not really fit to be stored in Settings/Preferences), to be used in other pages of my application, so how can I pass it around?

I can collect all this data that must be used in various pages in a single "GlobalData" object, but what are the pros and cons of each possibile solution, of the following ones.

I excluded:

- passing it as a NavigationParameter, because I see it as impractical to have to include the object each time I navigate to, I prefer the object to be available or instantiated everytime a page is created

I experimented with:

1 storing and retrieving from SQLite and LiteDB

2 storing and retrieving from MonkeyCache and Akavache

3 storing and retrieving from a global App object

4 injecting the object with Prism DI in each page

All the solutions work on my tests, starting from the easiest to implement, I would use 3, then 4, then 2, then 1.
Using a glboal App object is by far the easiest, I know the pros but what are the cons?
I just want to understand if there's something fundamentally wrong in each of the approach.

Thanks!

Comment: "most correct" is a matter of opinion, and there is no "right" answer.

Comment: I edited the question to have an answer not based on an opinion

Comment: @Mattia,According to your description, if the data is very large, overuse global app object may tax  memory and affect performance,I suggest you can use sqlite to store data.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT oh thanks, this is useful: how much data, as an order of magnitude, can be considered safe to be permanently stored in the App object for the lifetime of the application, without taxing it? Is there a difference on how memory is managed if an object stored in App and if it is rehydrated from db as a local object on each viewmodel that needs it?

Answer (score 1):

You missed the most obvious option - passing the data around during navigation.

`INavigationService.NavigateAsync` takes a parameter of type `INavigationParameters` which can store abitrary data. The same instance then shows up in the view model that's navigated to (if it implements `INavigationAware`).

Comment: Thanks, I considered and excluded it, but I didn't write it in the question

Comment: Well, I don't get how you want to _instantiate_ an object received from a web service each time you create a view model, but of course you can download it and put it anywhere (it really doesn't matter, as it's the wrong question to ask). If you _keep_ it around in some storage instead of _passing_ it from page to page, you'll likely run into a situation where you create a page with an _obsolete_ or _wrong_ instance of the object in the storage. So each and every page that touches the storage-service has to make sure to remove it if it gets invalid.

Comment: "put it anywhere (it really doesn't matter, as it's the wrong question to ask)". Not really, the 4 options I mentioned (and obviusly there are more) have different pros and cons, in terms of speed, testability, modularity etc... The invalidation is not an issue, the data is valid while used in that session.

Comment: So you have to be sure to always know the end of a session to invalidate the cache. I only see disadvantages when you store the object somewhere. Perhaps you can elaborate as to what makes you prefer a static cache over passing the object around, as that's, obviously, as fast as possible, perfectly testable and modular?

Comment: Yes invalidation is not an issue, that it is already taken care of. The user starts a session, moving between ViewModels, sometimes back and forth, downloading other data, complement it with data downloaded on the previous ViewModel, and at the end sending back to the server. So we're dealing with more than one dataobj, not all are needed in certain ViewModels, tha't why it makes sense to have a central repository. And we have background workmanager thread that may need to check the data. I was looking for considerations like the one of @CherryBu-MSFT

Answer (score 0):

I have found it useful to maintain singleton models for my view models to access. Some care needs to be taken to manage this data. I clear the data when it is not relevant. Since my workflow is fairly linear I populate it at key points in the workflow. Typically the models contain just DTOs and collections with initialization and clear methods.